# is a namespace but is used like a 'type'

Tags: c#

UPDATE

I've created the solution again.

```
File > New > Project > VisualC# > Console Application

Name : teststudent
Solution name : teststudent
```

Then from solution exploer I clicked on teststudent

```
Add > New Item > ADO.Net Entity Data Model > Generate from database
```

New connection :

```
save entity connection settings in App.Config as :

teststudententities
```

Which version of Entity Framework do you want to use?

```
6.0
```

Then I checked all tables.

```
Model Namespace:
teststudentModel
```

UPDATE ENDS

I'm trying to create a query to show all the records in a database table named students in Visual Studio 2013.
studentdb is the name of my database. I have established a connection to my SQL Server database. I can see the tables from the model in solution explorer. When I execute I get one build error :

```
'studentdb' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'
```

the program.cs file :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace studentdb
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Query1();
            }
            private static void Query1()
            {
                using (var context = new studentdb())
                {
                    var students = from studentdetails in context.students select studentdetails;
                    Console.WriteLine(" Query All students");
                    foreach (var student in students)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", student.studentid, student.surname);
                    }
                    Console.Write("Press enter to exit"); Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: for ``new studentdb()`` use full qualified name of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You namespace and one of the class name is same

```
namespace studentdb
using (var context = new studentdb())
```

I think you meant var context = new studententities() or something similar not studentdb()

Comment: I have tried :

namespace studentdb

using (var context = new studententities())

The type or namespace name 'studententities' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: how did u name your dbcontext while creating the edmx file? do a search for keyword context in visual studio then you should be able to someclassname : dbcontext. here someclassname is your entity context name and you should new that instead of new studentdb()

Comment: replace studentdb() with teststudententities()

Comment: Thanks that did it! It has to be the same name as used in the connection settings.

Answer (score 4):

Just rename namespace to something else at line 7

```
namespace anotherNamespace
{
```

Answer (score 0):

studentdb is the name of same namespace. So you can not use that like **studentdb()**. You can create **object** for only **classes** but not **namespaces**.